# Generating link during fetch vs during creation

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I a table like this:

**Categories:**

```
| cat_id | cat_name |
|--------|----------|
| 1      | tvs      |
| 2      | phones   |
| 3      | tablets  |
```

And then I have:

**Products:**

```
| product_id | product_name    | product_category |
|------------|-----------------|------------------|
| 1          | tv sony         | 1                |
| 2          | tv samsung      | 1                |
| 3          | phone htc       | 2                |
| 4          | phone motorolla | 2                |
| 5          | tablet apple    | 3                |
```

And someone goes into **index.php** where I get 10 random products from the DB. For creating the link I'd have to fetch the database again (to get the name of the category) and then I could do something like `mysite.com/phones/4` (that would be the link to `phone motorolla`).

Of course 10 wouldn't be too hard on the server but it's still another fetch on the database.

The other option is to fetch for the category name during the product creation, and generate a link there, something like:

```
| product_id | product_name    | product_category | product_link |
|------------|-----------------|------------------|--------------|
| 1          | tv sony         | 1                | tvs/1        |
| 2          | tv samsung      | 1                | tvs/2        |
| 3          | phone htc       | 2                | phones/3     |
| 4          | phone motorolla | 2                | phones/4     |
| 5          | tablet apple    | 3                | tablets/5    |
```

However the name of the category may change and so the link wouldn't work anymore. So what should I do? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) Do what seems simplest, worry about optimization only if it becomes a problem.

Comment: Why didn't you make a SQL JOIN between Products and Categories tables in order to get the product and category name ?

Comment: @Arrabidas92 I didn't knwo about SQL JOIN, I'm learning as I go, but now I have a question, in my categories table I actually have 3 columns, the third one being: `category_parent` which is a either NULL or an integer with the ID of the parent category, how could I use join with that?

Comment: I think you have a typo. It's `motorola`, not `motorolla` :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yep you are right, it's just an example though! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright Nick so in SQL you have something very powerful called JOIN. A join in SQL allows you to merge columns from different tables based on a key. Usually the key is a primary key or a foreign key.

In your case, it seems you have as primary keys : **cat_id** and **product_id**
And as foreign key you have : **product_category**
Based on your database schema, you can query your tables like this :

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, c.cat_name
FROM PRODUCTS p INNER JOIN CATEGORIES c 
ON p.product_category = c.cat_id
```

With this query you retrieve your product_id, product_name and cat_name based with only one query for your database.

Here is more info about joins in SQL => https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks this is very useful, I've a question though, I have a third column in the categories table, which is `category_parent` and is either `NULL` or an integer with the parent category id. Is there a way to use SQL JOIN for retrieving this too?

Comment: Of course you can retrieve whatever column you want. The one and only condition to make a join between tables is they have to be linked in some way with a key as I said.

Comment: Ok, other question, you used `p.` before the column name, is the letter `p` arbitrary?

Comment: Good question ! In SQL, you can rename column names and table names with a shorter alias. Here p and c are aliases for tables Products and Categories. It's a common habit in SQL to make aliases for very long queries to use shorter names. Another useful case to use aliases it's when you have a colum with a same name but in two different tables. In order to distinguish both columns, you have to put in front of your column name alias.column_name . If you forget to put it, you will probably have an error like "ambigous name of column" = which column do SQL have to take.

Comment: I only choose p because is the first letter of your table Products and c for Categories. It's another common habit.